# sphinix rt table schema is not updated

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Using sphinxsearch 2.2, I have this schema defined in `sphinx.conf`:

```
index topic
{
        type                    = rt
        path                    = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/topic
        rt_field                = title
        rt_field                = description
        rt_attr_timestamp       = created_at
}
```

When I save, and reinstall searchd (sing `searchd --stop` and then `searchd` again)
The schema is not reflected in the sphixQL:

```
MySQL [(none)]> desc topic;
+-------------+-----------+
| Field       | Type      |
+-------------+-----------+
| id          | bigint    |
| title       | field     |
| title       | field     |
| description | field     |
| likes       | uint      |
| created_at  | timestamp |
+-------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

As you can see, for some reason there are two `title` fields above. This does not change whatever change I make to `sphinx.conf`.

In order to update the schema, I have also tried to removed all /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/topic* files, but it did not make any difference.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just redefining the schema is not enough, as the index files will already exist.

That been said if you delete the index files, while `searchd` is shut down, the index will be regenerated empty, next time try to use it.